# Should I run Bitcoind / JSON RPC on a home server connecting to a VPS

Tags: bitcoind, security, json-rpc, server

I'm debating whether to run bitcoind/ JSON-RPC on a server from my house that takes requests from users on hosted VPS. While I'm not starting a bitcoin poker site, I can explain what I'm doing easier with that. A user sends bitcoins to a pre-generated address. When user sends bitcoins, the home server will see whether it is sent then tell the VPS, which will then give the user chips or credits.

My questions :

1. Will this eat up my internet from home assuming I have 100 gb bandwidth / 6-8 mbps upload speeds? If not, how many people can be served at a time?
2. Does anyone actually do this compared to using a hosted vps/dedicated server because they want security and don't want to rely on 3rd party services like blockchain?

Comment: Very similar to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7282/is-it-safe-to-run-bitcoind-on-another-server?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for that. I was trying to use a home dedicated server to prevent malicious vps admins. I think a process like this shouldn't eat up my bandwidth, but wondering if others did this.